# Is there a ready-to-go Steam Linux distribution iso?

Tags: steam, linux

Not sure this belongs here or super user, but Steam recently made it to official release status for Linux. Are there any distributions yet of an instantly bootable Flashdrive image or something with Steam? Something like Ubuntu or something but with Steam and it's dependencies prepackaged and ready to either be installed or can be used directly from a flashdrive?

I ask this because I normally use Arch Linux. Steam apparently *can* work for it, but it's not supported and there are a million different hoops I'd have to jump through to get it to work. It'd be nice to just put an image on a thumbdrive and be able to try out Steam For Linux without touching my actual OS

Comment: Looks like there is an official Arch package. "pacman -S steam" doesn't work?

Comment: If Windows 7 is truly the last Windows that Valve wants to officially support, this will become useful to Windows gamers too as Valve and Microsoft part ways.

Comment: I can guarantee you that Windows 7 will not be the last Windows that Valve supports.

Comment: This will need an update once SteamOS is released.

Comment: @AlanB - Reluctant support might be more apt. Depending on where Windows goes, Valve may not necessarily be following right behind but that doesn't mean it won't still work. The fact that Win8 was/is so horrible might be all the deterrent Valve needs to step slightly further away from Windows - slowly of course. Not to mention, most gamers wouldn't be caught dead on Win8 anyhow.

Comment: Well, it'll be interesting to see what they do with Half-Life 3 ... SteamOS exclusive for 12 months ?

Comment: I'm sure it won't disappoint as long as they don't rush it.

Answer (score 10):

Update: [Steam ISO](http://repo.steampowered.com/download/)

One could have such an iso with Steam with very little effort. If you would like an iso with a lot more than just Steam added, you will have to wait a little while longer.

In the mean time and for your purposes simply installing Steam will suffice. Steam is after all available in the Ubuntu store and automatically installs its own dependencies. Since Ubuntu/Debian is where Steam is essentially made to work the best, it makes the most sense to use such a distro. You could grab any of the numerous already existing Debian based distros most of which incorporate the Ubuntu store and install Steam from there. It's really that easy. You could also download the .deb from steampowered.com and install it through the store that way.

There are other things that one using a Steam distro might also like to have such as controller support to which I cannot comment on existing support but I imagine most USB/USB dongle based controllers will work fine out of the box. Other than that, there might be various aesthetic things that one might like to see in a Steam distro such as icons/theme/wallpaper/login customizations. Thankfully that's all super easy to do on any Debian OS provided someone has already created something to your liking.

---

More specific to the question, you can make a persistent Ubuntu flash image that is bootable and simply install Steam on it. Plug it into any computer, boot it, install graphics drivers on host machine and load up Linux Steam.

If you have a 4-8+GB drive, you're all set. The larger than 4GB drive would help if you wanted to install games in the spare space for steam. If you had a 32GB drive, set the 4GB to linux persistent install and the rest is game space.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

http://steamcommunity.com/linux

Steam can be set to run automatically at start like anything else once installed.

Alternatively, you could partition out ~30GB with GParted and install Ubuntu alongside your existing OS for testing purposes. There is the added benefit of the previous option being completely portable.

---

Even with the eventual arrival of SteamOS, it still holds true that it is extremely simple to set up nearly any Linux OS (primarily debian) with Steam though most would likely opt in for using the SteamOS instead (as would I - presumably - since it's not out yet) since it will have more features than simply distro + Steam.

---

SteamOS will be available for free as a Linux-based OS and will do everything you could need it to do including some claims of being able to play Windows/Mac games as well via a NVIDIA Shield-like streaming feature.

http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamOS/

Comment: You can easily add steam to start up with X (infact steam itself offers to do this however I've not tested it on gentoo).

It's likely you could pass some fullscreen option to it also however I've not verfied this.

Comment: I think the question is "has someone already created such an image?" Obviously it's possible to create one.

Comment: There is no pre-made image for something like this; it wouldn't make sense. You can use a Ubuntu CD ISO to create a USB Live installer and then make that USB Live installer persistent using the casper tool. Steam is just one of a million+ things you can do with a persistent bootable linux distro. You can also install the distro to a machine HDD from Live USB boot. You can add the PPA's for the graphics drivers (nvidia/ati) but there is no one driver that works on every machine and each machine would need to have it configured to work.

Comment: You underestimate both the history of live CDs and the variety of things that geeks create. Flexible driver configuration is a long-solved problem – that's a core part of what makes a live CD distribution work, and graphics drivers are not particularly special or hard in that regard. There is no technical nor common-sense reason for a Steam Live CD to not exist, except for simply not having been done yet.

Comment: For it to exist with that sole purpose just seems limited IMO. Consider you are really only adding 2 drivers (probably just one) that can be added with a PPA very easily in addition to Steam itself which also adds a PPA. Both of these things can be achieved with a boot up script on any live CD or written in only a few lines. You certainly could make a distro just for this but it's so easy to just do this.

Comment: The announcement of SteamOS proves my point.

Comment: If your point was: "There is no technical nor common-sense reason for a Steam Live CD to not exist, except for simply not having been done yet" then sure. Given that SteamOS is claiming to be able to do a lot more than just a standard Linux install with steam on it, it might make sense to make a whole new distro just for it. Is there however any reason that the features of SteamOS can't be incorporated into the standard Ubuntu install? Is SteamOS still a full-fledged operating system capable of a whole lot more than just being able to run Steam?

Comment: Is there a point to SteamOS besides branding assuming that the answers to my questions are no & yes. I'm not against SteamOS - I think it's a cool idea and I'll probably end up using it myself. That doesn't change that there is still no need to have a specialized build just for this purpose. You don't need one flavor of Linux to run KDE and another to run Gnome - nearly every distro can do both and that's my point. Ubuntu should be fully capable of doing everything that SteamOS can do.

Comment: That was my point, yes. This answer stills starts by making an unfounded (and empirically invalid) value judgement about the utility of niche live CDs, and then it uses that value judgement to extrapolate that a live CD won't/shouldn't exist. Not only does that faulty chain of reasoning reduce the quality of the answer, but it is also in contradiction of the (empirically true) assumption embeddeed in the question that niche live CDs are a common, normal thing.

Comment: In support of 7sided: the distro lists are overcrowded with livecd distros with no intelligible reason for exisiting

Comment: @horatio - That doesn't exactly support the idea that more should exist to further crowd an already overcrowded choice of distros many of which may well be redundant to others. That being said, I never disagreed or said that a distro for this purpose wouldn't exist but rather that it was unnecessary like so many others.

Comment: "should " and "don't" are not synonyms. To quote you: "There is no pre-made image for something like this; it wouldn't make sense." respectfully.

Comment: You got me. My position has shifted slightly converting the "wouldn't" to "shouldn't" or in other words, "why?". Boredom? Simply because it hasn't yet been done? There are all sorts of answers to that question but how is it that so many people are perfectly fine just installing Steam from the store or .deb file supplied online? It makes more sense to have a Debian distro with KDE as a base and all sorts of specialized KDE apps accompanying it. It makes a lot less sense to make a distro that you just install Steam on. What else to it is there? What more can be done to make it worthwhile?

Comment: @Enigma Frankly, the question isn't interested *any* in rumination on whether such a disc should exist, and it just adds noise to the answer. But to be clear, I'm not saying you should change it, I'm just explaining my downvote. You can disagree, and I can disagree, and that's all that need be done. :)

Comment: The actual state of reality is that there currently, to the best of my knowledge, is no such iso in existence. I am entirely in touch with that state of reality but in the event that such a state changes, as it will in time, I am open to comment on the extent of such changes. Within the question lies many questions some of which could be interpreted as, "how can I easily install Steam on arch linux?" or "Is there a one step solution to my problem?". Currently there is no 1 step solution but I offered a 2 step solution more or less.

Comment: By state of reality, I mean that it is not odd, unusual, or unexpected for a live CD for a niche to exist, let alone for such a large "niche" as running Steam. The answer wastes a lot of words (in the lede, no less!) pontificating on why that would be ridiculous, while reality chugs along disproving these entirely extraneous assertions. So, to the point: that's my -1. I'm just letting you know.

Comment: The question is open to all sorts of interpretations based on some inherently vague and open-ended questions: "Are there any distributions yet of an instantly bootable Flashdrive image *or something* with Steam? *Something like Ubuntu* or *something* but with Steam and it's dependencies prepackaged and *ready to either be installed* or can be used directly from a flashdrive?" - Specifically whether there is a package that has a "ready to be installed" condition.

Comment: I did not say that "*a* live CD for *a* niche to exist" is "odd, unusual, or unexpected". I specifically am referring to this niche and this aforementioned live CD as being an unnecessary one without a considerable amount more to it than distro X + Steam. With that in mind, I am also expecting Steam on Linux to grow, and massively at that. That still doesn't change that at this current point in time, and without additional considerations, it is unlikely and or impractical that one would make a distro + Steam and end it right there. The OP asks for Steam and no more.

Comment: With regard to my comment: "There is no pre-made image for something like this; it wouldn't make sense." - The "something like this" that I was referring to was the one time install of Steam, PPA, .deb, or otherwise. My statement that "it wouldn't make sense" is referring to the creation of a distro that is in entirety an exact duplicate of Ubuntu xx.xx with the single addition of Steam.

Comment: "unlikely or impractical" and "wouldn't make sense" is the kind of thing that's out of touch with reality that I'm talking about. Unlikely and impractical may be true, but that has nothing to do with live CDs. "Wouldn't make sense" isn't a reason for a live CD to not exist either. (If it did, many that do exist wouldn't. QED.) If it's not clear, I don't object to the substance of the solution in the answer, just the misguided musings that introduce it. There is too much of unfounded opinion (much contradicting reality) in this answer for it to be *good*.

Comment: Were not talking about *all* live CD's here. What you are saying is true for live CD's on the whole. Would you make a distro with just Blender 3D installed? Just straight up vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 + blender. New distro worthy? Think people will bother to download it? No it's not and no they won't. What is distro worthy is http://ubuntustudio.org/ which does that and a lot more. It's specialized, and it has purpose outside of the vanilla Ubuntu. It comes pre-packaged and architecturally customized for studio work. That is what SteamOS will be for the gaming niche presumably and that makes sense.

Comment: You may not have properly interpreted my "misguided musings" and if it was a lack of clarity on my part I am sorry but for the sake of this question and my answer, I am and was speaking entirely about a vanilla install of Ubuntu + Steam because that's all you need to do to "try out Steam For Linux without touching my actual OS" as the OP wanted to do.

Comment: If you care to specifically point out this "unfounded opinion" I can change it, or, since stack exchange is a community site, you can. I won't be offended. Giving me a down-vote because my answer doesn't adhere to your ideals about live CD's on the whole isn't exactly reasonable when the question pertains to a specific case. Granted, I have made several changes to my answer and new things have come to light (SteamOS announcement) and perhaps you still hold on because of my originally misinterpreted comment that a Steam iso would *never* exist, which I never said.